# Can't return false to an link which is created by jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

Well, I inserted an anchor tag with jquery:

```
 $.post(url, {key:key}, function(data) { 
    $('#links').html(data); 
    });
```

data returned from a php file is:

```
<a href="#" class="some-class">Hypertext<a>
```

When this link is clicked i want to return false so i did:

```
 <a href="#" class="some-class" onclick="someFunction(); return false">Hypertext</a>
```

but it isn't returning false, but the function is called. I tried to return false from the function it isn't working either.

And when I tried to use:

```
$('.some-class').click(function() {
   // something
   });
```

this didn't call the function. I couldn't find a way to fix this, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `on()` with a delegated event handler as the `.some-class` element is being dynamically appended. You'll also want to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the standard link behaviour. Try this:

```
$('#links').on('click', '.some-class', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop link behaviour
    // do something...
})
```

Comment: This didn't work, may be cuz #link is also a dynamically appended element?

Comment: @user1918890 yes that would be the reason. In that case you need to replace `#links` with the closest parent element which is not dynamically appended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation using [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#links').on('click', '.some-class', function(){
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind click when content are loaded.